# pip - Why can't I install this package from source?

Tags: python, pip

I git cloned this repository https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3 and added a harmless print line but am not able to install it from source i.e. the following commands below

```
git clone https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3
cd bullet3
pip install .
```

returns me the error

```
...
examples/pybullet/pybullet.c(11954): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data    
examples/pybullet/pybullet.c(12132): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ha_ha\anaconda3\envs\mogaze-source\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ha_ha\\Desktop\\Haziq\\datasets\\mogaze-source\\bullet3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ha_ha\\Desktop\\Haziq\\datasets\\mogaze-source\\bullet3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

What is happening?

Comment: What OS are you using?  If you're using Windows we can't help you (those look like Windows error logs!).